# how to set locale correctly manually?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, locale

I'm building a docker image based on `Ubuntu 14.04`  and am having troubles to set the locale correctly.

(I know 14.04 is EOL and all but it should still work as well, right? I was denied support from the Ubuntu people on askubuntu.com, hence I'm trying my luck here)

My `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
COPY .bashrc /root/.bashrc
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential \
                       locales
RUN dpkg-reconfigure locales
WORKDIR /home/prs/
```

Where `.bashrc` is:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

it will build with no errors `docker build -t "test" .` but when I run it, I get the following output:

```
$ docker run -it test
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory
root@d09247a538eb:/# source /root/.bashrc 
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
root@d09247a538eb:/#
```

I also tried:

```
echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/locale.conf
```

I still get:

```
# locale-gen
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```

What's going on with this? And how can the locale be set correctly?

**UPDATE:**

It seems like that if I base my container image off of `Ubuntu 18.04`, I get to choose a `locale` when I type `# dpkg-reconfigure locales` but with `14.04` (which is what I currently need) I get the following:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```

AS suggested below by Eduardo Trápani (@EduardoTrápani), I also tried to run the locale setting manually:

```
# echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" | sudo tee -a /etc/locale.gen
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
# locale-gen
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```

Another hint may be, that there is nothing in the locales/sup[ported.d directory (which should be the result of `locale-gen` if I understand this correctly from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/locale-gen.8.html):

```
# ls -l /var/lib/locales/supported.d/
```

total 0

Comment: Does this also happen on a more modern Ubuntu, such as 20.04?

Comment: not quite the same, please see **UPDATE** above.

Comment: Try modifying `/etc/locale.gen` and running `locale-gen` like in [stackoverflow.com/a/28406007/10931455](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406007/10931455).

Comment: @Freddy there was no `/etc/locale.gen`, I had to create it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the locale to `/etc/locale.gen`, build it, and then you can use it:

```
$ sudo echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" | sudo tee -a /etc/locale.gen
$ sudo locale-gen
```

You can put those commands in your docker file.

Comment: Hi Eduardo, I did add both these commands to my Dockerfile but it still complains: `bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory` even though there now is a `/etc/locale.gen` with the following contents: `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`

Comment: `locale-gen` should report the locales it is building. If there is an error inside the docker context you might be able to see it if you run it manually.

Comment: docker doesn't print more than `RUN locale-gen` & `---> Running in 52a4316f2a63` even when I build with `--no-cache` and when I execute `locale-gen` when the image is running, I get `/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)`

Comment: I also updated the OP above with the output when running it manually.

Comment: Is that the full output *when you do it manually*, just the error and then the prompt, right away? Because `locale-gen` does not stop if it cannot set the locale, it's more a warning than an error.

Comment: it returns right away. It does say `warning` - although, `# echo $LC_ALL` does return `en_US.UTF-8`. I'm trying to run a `bitbake` command and the error I get reads *Please use a locale setting which supports utf-8. Python can't change the filesystem locale after loading so we need a utf-8 when python starts or things won't work.*

Comment: Last thing I'd try is to explicitely install `locales` with `RUN apt-get install -y locales` **before** you run `locale-gen`. Because [all needed files should be there](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/locales/filelist) but your docker image might have a trimmed down version of the package.

Comment: I already do this, I have `RUN apt-get install -y build-essential \
                       locales` (and a few other packages) followed by `RUN echo "C.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen` in my Dockerfile

Comment: I have reformulated my question, as you've answered this one. Thanks, if you like to see,m I've posted this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65525716/why-do-i-get-a-locale-error-even-thougfh-it-is-set

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're seeing is that by default, no locales are built into Docker container except `C` (also known as `POSIX`) and `C.UTF-8` (the UTF-8 version).  That's because glibc ships with a huge number of locales which take up a decent amount of space and Debian and Ubuntu, to save space, ship only compressed versions in the `locales` package, requiring the specific locales to be built on the system.

If you're just looking for an English language locale with UTF-8, then `C.UTF-8` may meet your needs and avoid needing to build a new locale in your container.  You can simply use `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 docker run -it test`.

However, if you need a U.S. English locale specifically (e.g., because you for some strange reason really like the Avoirdupois system and want to use it with `LC_MEASUREMENT`), your easiest solution is to install the `locales-all` package.  That provides pre-built versions of all locales.

Alternatively, if you're desperate for space, you can update your Dockerfile to add this line:

```
RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen
```

That will build just the locale you want.

The final solution is to have your `.bashrc` detect whether your locale is valid and set it to something else if it's not.  Since, despite being a native English speaker, I often use a French-language locale, which is not always available on all systems I use, I've adopted this approach.  You can run the following command, which will exit 0 if the locale `$locale` exists and nonzero if it does not:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX=locale_h -E 'exit !setlocale(LC_ALL, $ARGV[0]);' "$locale" \
  2>/dev/null
```

Comment: HI bk2204, I did try the `C.UTF-8` version which worjked fine but I unfortunately need to set it to `en_US.UTF-8` and there is no `locales-all` package I could install.

Comment: The `locales-all` package is available in newer versions, such as 16.04 and newer.  It sounds like you'll need to update to an OS version that presently has support and updates.